# How do I COUNT(*) in a SQL query all the distinct values based on a value in a row?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I'm trying to count the number of distinct teams that exist where the Status = Active in a SQL query from 2 columns (team and team_2). How would I do this?

```
Team                Team_2               Nationality     Status
Crystal Palace FC   Everton FC            France        Active
Crystal Palace FC   Everton FC             England      Active
Everton FC          Crystal Palace FC      Ireland    Sacked
Everton FC          Crystal Palace FC      England    Active
```

In this Scenario, the result would be 2

Comment: The specification isn't very clear.  Is the expected result 2, because we get a list of all the names in the `Team` column plus a list of all the names in the `Team_2` column, all listed together, and then we throw out all the duplicates.  Or, is the expected result 2 because we are counting (CPFC,EFC)  and (EFC,CPFC).  To ask that another way, if we added a fifth row to the table e.g. `('Foo','Bar','','Active')` would the expected result be 3 or 4?  The form of the query really depends on what we are attempting to accomplish; without a specification, we're just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

Without a more complete specification, we're just guessing at what the query is trying to accomplish.

One possible interpretation of the requirement:  get the set of values that exist in `team` column, along with the set of values that exist in the `team_2` column, concatenate all of those values into a single list, and then eliminate duplicates from the list, and get a count of the rows with non-NULL values...

To satisfy that, we could do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(v.team) AS cnt
  FROM ( 
         SELECT t1.team
           FROM mytable t
          WHERE t.status = 'Active'
          UNION
         SELECT t2.team_2
           FROM mytable t2
          WHERE t.status = 'Active'
       ) v
```

Note that the `UNION` set operator will force duplicate values to be eliminated.  If we added a fifth row  `('Foo','Bar','','Active')` to the table, then we expect this query to return 4, because we are counting four distinct values ...

There are other possible interpretations of the specification, and those would not be satisfied by the query above.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use `count(distinct)`:

```
select count(distinct team)
from t
where status = 'Active';
```

Comment: What if there were 2 team rows (Team_1 and Team_2) and I still needed to find all distinct names in those two rows?

Comment: i think you mean columns and you could concatenate them: ```count (distinct team || team_2)``` or ```count(distinct concat(team, team_2))```